# Python DB Access from CGI script in Apache Web Server Issue

Tags: odbc

I have a python script that when runs outside of Apache environment (on RedHat) connects to a remote MS SQL Server via ODBC correctly and returns data as expected. It uses an ODBC driver installed at /opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0 .

When running the same python code as a CGI script from Apache Web Server, there is an error that says

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MY_DSN;UID=user1;PWD=pw1');
```

> [Fri Jan 04 11:51:59 2013] [error] [client 172.19.1.136] ('01000',
>   "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   '/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0' : file not
>   found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

The path and file /opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0 does exist. Like I said when running the script from the shell it works fine. It fails to load the above library when executed inside the httpd.

I tried to add a Directory entry into httpd.conf, but that didn't seem to help.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing an identical problem when attempting a similar operation on plpython in postgresql. The same exact code works in the shell.